# in javascript onchange i wish to convert date input numeric (01022013) to date format )01/02/2013)

Tags: javascript, validation, data-conversion

i want to create a form where user enter 01022013 format and onchange it should convert to date format . and similarly onfocus it should be in numeric format.
pl help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'01022013'.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '$1/$2/$3') // -> "01/02/2013"
```